# Pivotal .NetCore 3.1 dotnet-runtime Error During Deployment

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, cloud-foundry, .net-runtime

I want to deploy my project using Pivotal from Bamboo. During the deployment of my **.NetCore 3.1** project, I'm getting the error "*Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install*". The deployment stack is set to **cflinuxfs3**.

I've tried specifying dotnet runtime version (3.1 and 3.1.5) in .csproj file but it got the same error so I removed it.

I've also created a buildpack.yml file and specified the .netcore sdk version as 3.1.x in there.

I'm sharing the property group from csproj and the manifest.yml file.

**-- Error Log --**

> Downloading app package...
> Downloaded app package (6.4M)
> -----> Dotnet-Core Buildpack version 2.3.12
> -----> Supplying Dotnet Core
> -----> Installing libunwind 1.4.0
> Copy[/tmp/buildpacks/b7bd2a36eb284e204524c677d2dbbfa2/dependencies/a54cfafce3d2a14e4f96777d5fd471f4/libunwind_1.4.0_linux_noarch_cflinuxfs3_05e08b22.tgz]
> using the default SDK
> -----> Installing dotnet-sdk 3.1.301
> Copy[/tmp/buildpacks/b7bd2a36eb284e204524c677d2dbbfa2/dependencies/b422801667458a262ba26a3117b93e4f/dotnet-sdk_3.1.301_linux_x64_any-stack_80a771e4.tar.xz]
>
> -----> Installing dotnet-runtime 3.1.5
> Copy[/tmp/buildpacks/b7bd2a36eb284e204524c677d2dbbfa2/dependencies/40b5a460524fe7f1795c876445349a31/dotnet-runtime_3.1.5_linux_x64_any-stack_1aa84612.tar.xz]
>
> -----> Finalizing Dotnet Core
> **ERROR** Unable to install dotnet-runtime: could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install    Failed to compile droplet: Failed to
> run finalize script: exit status 12    Exit status 223    Cell
> ffe536bc-374c-46b5-a620-e3366dab6b22 stopping instance
> b71ecb48-0083-4fd1-8f59-3a77b05de0e0
>
> Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile
> phase

**-- .csproj --**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
    <ConcurrentGarbageCollection>true</ConcurrentGarbageCollection>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**-- manifest.yml --**

```
---
applications:
- name: projectName
  memory: 1G
  timeout: 240
  instances: 1
  routes:
   - route: routeAddress
  services:
   - ARCHITECTURE.SERVICES-TST.ServiceRegistry
   - ProjectName.Redis
   - ProjectName.Dynatrace
   - ProjectName.ConfigServer
  env:
    DT_TAGS: ((appName)) ((dc))-((env))
    TZ: country
    ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: environmentName
    SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_LABEL: configLabel
```

Comment: If you can provide a demo app that reproduces the problem, I'll take a closer look and see if I can update my answer with any more details.

Comment: I am getting the same issue where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what is happening.

1. The [code is looking at the RuntimeFrameworkVersion in your `.csproj` file](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/blob/v2.3.12/src/dotnetcore/project/project.go#L333).
2. [When that is empty, it's going to look at the TargetFramework](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/blob/v2.3.12/src/dotnetcore/project/project.go#L343) and attempt to find a substring match using the regex `netcoreapp(.*)`.
3. [It is expecting that to have a single match](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/blob/v2.3.12/src/dotnetcore/project/project.go#L344), but in your case it does not, [so you get that error message](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/dotnet-core-buildpack/blob/v2.3.12/src/dotnetcore/project/project.go#L351): `could not find a version of dotnet-runtime to install`.

Based on your `.csproj` file, it seems like what you have should be OK though. I did a quick check and the regex works and returns the version.

You could try setting `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` which would take a slightly different code path and might work for you.

You are trying to perform a [source-based deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/dotnet-core/index.html#source-based). You could try `dotnet publish` first followed by a [Framework Dependent Deployment](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/dotnet-core/index.html#framework-dependent) which again would force a different code path.

It might be that the buildpack isn't finding your file, but it's hard to say without more info.